# Snazzy Maps in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, snazzymaps

I set up a nice map in my rails application. Everything is working fine but I cannot style the map with SnazzyMaps.

Here is my map.js file:

```
import GMaps from 'gmaps/gmaps.js';

const mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement) { // don't try to build a map if there's no div#map to inject in
  const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
  const markers = JSON.parse(mapElement.dataset.markers);
  const mapMarkers = map.addMarkers(markers);
  mapMarkers.forEach((marker, index) => {
      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        // map.setCenter(markers[index]);
        markers[index].infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      })
    });

  if (markers.length === 0) {
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else if (markers.length === 1) {
    map.setCenter(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng);
    map.setZoom(14);
  } else {
    map.fitLatLngBounds(markers);
  }
}

import { autocomplete } from '../components/autocomplete';

// [...]
autocomplete();
```

On SnazzyMaps they give the following example. My question is, where shall I insert which part of this code in my own file. Been trying it for a while now but cannot make it work. Here is SnazzyMaps example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snazzy Maps Super Simple Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            /* Set a size for our map container, the Google Map will take up 100% of this container */
            #map {
                width: 750px;
                height: 500px;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- 
            You need to include this script tag on any page that has a Google Map.

            The following script tag will work when opening this example locally on your computer.
            But if you use this on a localhost server or a live website you will need to include an API key. 
            Sign up for one here (it's free for small usage): 
                https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

            After you sign up, use the following script tag with YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY replaced with your actual key.
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY"></script>
        -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                // Basic options for a simple Google Map
                // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
                var mapOptions = {
                    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                    zoom: 11,

                    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

                    // How you would like to style the map. 
                    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
                    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"weight":"2.00"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#9c9c9c"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#7b7b7b"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#c8d7d4"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#070707"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}]
                };

                // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
                // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

                // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Snazzy!'
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Snazzy Maps Super Simple Example</h1>
        <h2><a href="https://snazzymaps.com/style/8097/wy" target="_blank">WY</a></h2>

        <!-- The element that will contain our Google Map. This is used in both the Javascript and CSS above. -->
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your template? are you using Vuejs ?

Comment: Sorry but I am really unexperienced with javascript. I tried to google/understand what you mean but I dont really know what you mean by template/vue js.  All I did was insert <div
  id="map"
  style="width: 100%;
  height: 280px;"
  data-markers="<%= @markers.to_json %>">
</div> in my view. And secondly insert the above mentioned code in 'gmaps/gmaps.js'.

Answer (score 0):

To set the style using **Gmaps** library, you need to define the styles and then set it to the current map as below:

```
const map = new GMaps({ el: '#map', lat: 0, lng: 0 });
var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#00ffe6" },
        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    }, {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: "simplified" }
      ]
    }, {
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
      ]
    }
];

map.addStyle({
    styledMapName:"Styled Map",
    styles: styles,
    mapTypeId: "map_style"  
});

map.setStyle("map_style");
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/hpneo/gmaps/blob/master/examples/styled_maps.html

Comment: Really dont get this Vuejs stuff. its quite frustrating without really having a deeper understanding of Javascript. Asking a complete noobish question: Where shall I insert this code? In my map.js file or in my view? Sorry for that.